Hide notification content from notification badge in windows 10
I am trying to hide the content of the notifications on my screen while using the device (not on the lock screen). I looked in the settings but couldn't find anything. I also tried editing the registry but don't know much about that.


Would Presentation Mode be useful? "When you enable presentation mode, your device stays awake and system notifications are turned off." https://winaero.com/enable-presentation-mode-windows-10/ That temporarily disables notifications completely.

I don't want to completely hide the notifications; I just want to hide the content within them. For example, if there's a notification from Chrome, I want it to show that there's a notification from Chrome, but not display the detailed content of the notification.

That would have to be a setting in Chrome, not in Windows. Firefox, for example, lets one set the language for notifications. Perhaps you can have notifications shown in Miðgarðr or Vulcan?

chrome does not have that setting is there any other way
